# Ubuntu is INCREDIBLY slow

Tags: performance, mac

I recently decided to overhaul my 13 year old iMac and replace the OS with Ubuntu to breath in some new life. Everything is up to date, but it's laggy as hell. And when I say laggy, I mean 60+ seconds just to register a keystroke. 120+ seconds to open up programs. 180+ seconds to log in. That type of laggy.

I know I don't have much info about my computer, but are there any general things I can try to make Ubuntu actually usable? I'm hoping my hardware isn't holding it back *too* much, though I know with a 13 year old iMac I'm probably going to experience some sort of lag. I just didn't think it would be literally minutes worth of it for the simplest things.

I also have no idea what I'm doing, hence a not very technical post.

Comment: A system that old would be better with a light weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie  Many suggest Lubuntu.

Comment: You've provided few details about your hardware, but more importantly for me would be what Ubuntu product you're talking about.  I'm replying here on a 2009 dell desktop running the current *development* release and it's good.. (and FYI I'm using a lighter *flavor* as performance is faster; Lubuntu actually), but software stack details (Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Desktop? Ubuntu Server? what release etc) are the starting point you've missed. FYI:  I currently use devices as old as from 2005 in QA-testing, but testing to ensure it runs vs living with it full time mean app/desktop/flavor choice matters

Comment: Quick thing to try is to run Ubuntu in a live usb session - it should perform the same as an installed version (though slightly slower than a ‘good’ installation due to usb being slower than sata) - but it does take the hdd and any installation problems out  of the equation for troubleshooting, and it’s quick / easy to do.

Comment: @oldfred I tried to install Lubuntu but now Ubuntu won't boot from my USB Drive. So I put in my Lubuntu bootable, do everything the same as I did to install Ubuntu, and it just opens Ubuntu. No Lubuntu no nothin'.

Comment: @guiverc I tried to install Lubuntu to see if it is my hardware, but it won't open up from the bootable USB anymore. No matter what I do it won't boot from the USB. And I'm using the same tools and shortcuts as I did to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Please be specific; Ubuntu is *vague* without telling us if you mean Ubuntu Core, Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, and what release you mention.  Lubuntu is likewise rather *vague* (though it does limit it to a Desktop release as it's all you provided, but no software stack details). I am rather *familiar* with Lubuntu but you've given too few details for my knowledge to be useful as I don't know what release; what if any kernel stack options you have etc, or you opted for an *unsupported* system which I'd not expect to be helpful/work well on a Mac...  Providing release details or ISO details